# 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have deployed a website. It work well when I access from internal network (the network on my company). But, the website has error display UI when I try access the website on the public internet. The root cause of isssue that the website cannot get resource files (css).
The browser show errror message: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (ModSecurity Action)". 
So, I try to access the bundled resource file is error, and the browser display the error message "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied."
I think I have a problem with the network or firewall.
Could you give me the solutions to resolve this issue?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSWEq.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqqOo.png)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Please add this key in your web.config .if not there .

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
```

If still same issue then let me know .

You should put this key to allow the request access

```
<system.webServer> 
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

Comment: have you tried this runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests ?

Comment: This key (runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests) was added, but the issue is still there!

Comment: SSL is enabled in your project ?

Comment: Yes, SSL is enabled

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/822322/you-receive-an-http-error-403-forbidden-error-while-you-work-in-asp-ne

Answer (score 0):

I experienced same issue when migrated to new server which had ModSecurity (Web Application Firewall under Plesk). App run just fine when opened from a browser on the server. The website had some external chat apps (tawk.to) which added some cookies triggering some rules (Detects basic SQL authentication bypass attempts 2/3).

Issue can temporarily be fixed by changing ModSecurity (Web application firewall mode) to **Detection only**. Also **ModSecurity Log File** can be checked to understand why request was rejected and disable specific rules.

On my server active ruleset was **OWASP (free) running on IIS (ModSecurity 2.9)**

This is what is specified under Plesk for Windows;

> To find out why an HTTP request cannot be completed for a website:
>
> 1. Click the ModSecurity Log File link below and open the audit log in
>    a new browser window.
> 2. Use Search (Ctrl+F in most web browsers) to find events for the website (the domain name) that experiences problems. For example,
>    your_domain.tld. The browser will highlight entries like HOST:
>    your_domain.tld.
> 3. In three lines above the highlighted entry, find a string like --eece5138-B--. The eight symbols between hyphens (in our example, eece5138) are the ID of the event triggered by the HTTP request.
> 4. Search further for other entries with the same event ID. Look for an entry with the letter H after the event ID (in our example,
>    eece5138-H--). This entry contains the ID and description of the
>    security rule triggered while checking the HTTP request. The security
>    rule ID is an integer number in quotation marks with the prefix id in
>    square brackets (for example, [id "340003"]).
> 5. Find a security rule ID in the event using a substring (for example, [id "3).
> 6. Switch off the security rule with this ID in the Security rules section below: enter the security rule ID (digits only) into the
>    Security rule IDs field and click OK.

Additionally check https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/12377864021143-A-website-hosted-in-Plesk-or-the-webmail-page-for-it-fails-to-load-when-ModSecurity-is-enabled